# Remove leading zeroes but not all zeroes in C#

Tags: c#

I have the string value  `000001` and need to get the last three digits -  `001`

Zeroes quantity before `001` can be different and the value itself can be `011` or `111`

```
     Value   Expected Value
       000   000
      0001   001
     00011   011
    000111   111
   0001111   Not a case
```

There is a way to remove all leading zeros `value.TrimStart('0')` but how to keep zeros that are in scope of the last three chars?

Is there a way to trim till specified chars left?

Comment: Assuming you have "1111" would you expect "111" or "1111"?

Comment: PadLeft with 0 to a width of 3 after you trim

Comment: @NineBerry value has three digits only maximum, so the case 1111 is invalid for me, only 0000111

Comment: It may be easier to convert to an integer and the convert back to a string with leading zeroes.

Comment: Assuming you have "11" would you expect "11" or "011"?

Comment: @NineBerry should be 011

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do a trim followed by a [`PadLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-5.0):

```
value.TrimStart('0').PadLeft(3,'0')
```

Comment: Looks like the suggested answer worked fine for all my cases, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since you need last three characters, extracting will do.

```cs
string value = "12345"; // "0012";
Console.WriteLine(value.Substring(value.Length - 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern C# we have quite a nice way of expressing parts of a string with indexes and ranges

```
value[^3..];
```

It means "3 from the end, to the end, of value".

Your question was a bit confusing; you seem to say that your value will always have more than 3 digits so this will be safe to do.. If it won't always have more than 3 digits you could either PadLeft it first, or, more compactly, concat your value onto "00" (assuming you'll always have a digit)

```
value.PadLeft(3,'0')[^3..];

("00"+value)[^3..];
```

Comment: That one value[^3..]; really gorgeous! Thanks!